# Setting text for the current page

Tags: html, css, url, redirect, web-config

I need to know how to set the text that shows on the tab of the page you are in (The upper section that would show what page it is). On my site that I am developing, it just says the URL (www.thehideout.somee.com) and not the actual page name. I was wondering if this can be done with the Web.Config file? If not, it's fine; any solution works. This is what I mean.
[image: The Tabs]

I want the highlighted area to say "Index - TGH" and not the URL itself, if its possible.

Another Question is how do I get extensionless URLs (preferably using the Web.Config file)? I tried everywhere, tutorials and answers from here to there, doesn't work except me a error for every page. I just want to be able to type in www.thehideout.somee.com/games or www.thehideout.somee.com/2048 with it redirecting to www.thehideout.somee.com/games.html (not the folder as it gives a forbidden 403 access error) and www.thehideout.somee.com/games/2048.html as my classmates are very confused on why it doesn't work; please help with this also: Here's my Web.Config file that is fitted for a custom error page; please if you have a solution, fit it for my web.config!

```
<configuration>

   <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />

      <customErrors mode="on" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
         <remove statusCode="404"/>
         <error statusCode="404" path="/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: That's called page title! Open your `index.html` page. See that `<head>` section there? Just add this: `<title>Index - TGH</title>`

Comment: Thanks @LcSalazar, it helps alot! You're very friendly. Got any idea for the extensionless URLs?

Comment: You're welcome. See posted answer...

Comment: This should get you pointed in the right direction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index

Comment: @Hungerstar Thanks :) LcSalazar Sorry, the posted answer didn't show up right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called page title!

Open your `index.html` page. See that `<head>` section there? Just add this:

```
<head>
    <title>Index - TGH</title>
</head>
```

Now, about the "extensionless" URL's:

That behavior you see around the web, is often handled by an architecture named **MVC**. The friendly URL's are actually Method names and Views, combined.

Sorry, but there's no short explanation on how you should put this to work on your website. Is is a whole architecture pattern that you have to learn how to implement.

Since you're on ASP.NET, take a look at [**ASP.NET MVC**](http://www.asp.net/mvc). You'll find many "Getting Started" and Tutorial guides.

Comment: Thanks, but about the Extensionless URLs; I use www.somee.com for hosting, and I'm not sure if that MVC program will be able to link with that or if I'll have to structure a whole new site, any more info about that would be nice.

Comment: @TheGamingHideout, MVC is not a program. Is an architecture. You would need to build a new Project and learn to develop in this system. And yes, `somee.com` accepts MVC.

Comment: You also don't need to do an MVC to have extension-less paths. If your site doesn't require a lot of automation or even a database you can **most likely** do this with file naming and directory structure. Example: `example.com/hello/` would look like this on your host: `/hello/index.html`. Most servers will look for and `index.[some extension here]` file in a directory as the default file to use when a user attempts to access a directory.

Comment: @hungerstar Unfortunately, at Somee when creating a file, if I don't add an extension it outputs it as a plain file, not for anything; just a simple "File" extension, so that won't work.

Comment: @TheGamingHideout why would you not add an extension? Have you followed the link I provided in the comments to your question? Do you understand the information on that page? This is the list of default documents that my install of IIS 7 will serve if a specific file is not requested: `Default.htm`, `Default.asp`, `index.htm`, `index.html`, `iistart.htm`, `default.aspx`. Yours might be different. If you were to visit a URL like `example.com/hello/` the server would look for one of those files listed above to present to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [title tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) to the `head` of your page.

**Example:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Page Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```